# 3600PPR NEMA 17 Stepper Motor PPR

Tags: motor, closed-loop

What if any additional components would I need to make a NEMA 17 stepper motor have 3600 pulses per revolution? Do I need one or both gearboxes and encoders. My application requires fine degree adjustments that can move the motor up and down in small increments (~0.1 degrees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "microstepping".  It is a technique used on the driver to drive a stepper motor in smaller increments than single stepping.

1/16 microstepping will get you 3200 PPR, while 1/32 will yield 6400 (based on a common 200 step/rev NEMA 17 motor).

This is very common, and many, if not most, stepper drivers will do this.

[Here is how it works.](https://www.zaber.com/articles/microstepping-tutorial)